# Plot masks with several categories, and omit background (matplotlib)

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, imshow

I have two arrays: an image and a mask. The mask has different categories: 0 to 4. I want to plot an overlay over the image, but not show the '0' category (just don't show it, or have it be completely transparent).

This is my code:

```
# Plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 4, dpi=300, figsize=(20, 10))
cmap_mask = ListedColormap(['black', 'red', 'green', 'yellow'])
for index, channel in enumerate(channels):
    # Top row without masks
    ax[0, index].imshow(image[index, slice, :, :], cmap='gray')
    ax[0, index].set_title(channel, fontweight='bold')
    ax[0, index].get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    ax[0, index].get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
    # Bottom row with masks
    ax[1, index].imshow(image[index, slice, :, :], cmap='gray')
    ax[1, index].imshow(mask[slice, :, :], alpha=.7, cmap=cmap_mask)
    ax[1, index].get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    ax[1, index].get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
```

I've spent far too long on this already. The plot looks decent, but I'm darkening the background (on account of the black, but it's the best plot I got thus far). I tried working with `np.ma.masked_where`, but I couldn't make it work.

Comment: You might want to try `cmap_mask = ListedColormap(['none', 'red', 'green', 'yellow'])`

Comment: I can't believe it was that easy...